# MYSQL Query timestamp comparison

Tags: mysql, database

Given a table with a column that contains a timestamp, I would like to count the number of instances where the `TIMEDIFF(now(), timeStamp)` is greater than some value. The issue I ran into is implementing this all into a statement. My efforts:

```
SELECT COUNT*()
FROM sometable
WHERE (SELECT TIMEDIFF(now(),column_from_sometable) > 10
```

I'm just not quite sure how to use the `TIMEDIFF` in the where statement to use it for a comparison. (Apparently you must use `SELECT` to call the method, and then I'm just not sure how to access the column from `sometable`in that statement).

Comment: Is `COUNT*()` a typo? Did you mean `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a sub select provided the column `column_from_sometable` belong to same table `sometable`. You can dimply include in `WHERE` condition like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sometable
WHERE TIMEDIFF(now(),column_from_sometable) > 10
```

You can as well simplify this by adding the condition in your aggregate function like

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TIMEDIFF(now(),column_from_sometable) > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM sometable
```

Comment: I think the first is simpler. I think the key is: In order to output a result set, you need a `SELECT` somewhere. The examples for `TIMEDIFF()` use a `SELECT` just to get a simple result set without using a table. Within a query, you can use the function without putting `SELECT` in front of it.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, that correct but I have seen many people (Here in SO) prefer the 2nd option rather :)

Comment: @Rahul If there's no difference in performance I prefer code that's easier to understand. Most times it's code with a few lines more. So I agree with Marcus (+1 for both)

Comment: That was a typo indeed. Thank you for your solution, that is what I needed!